# Why do I get this error in the Ultrassonic context?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have installed multiple libraries from ultrassonic and the last one I installed was " ultrasonic-master library". Can it be a library issue?

I have this code using ultrasonic sensor but I'm getting the **'unsigned int Ultrasonic::timing()' is private within this context**

What can I try to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <Ultrasonic.h> 


const int IN4 = 6;  
const int IN3 = 7;  
const int IN2 = 5; 
const int IN1 = 4;  
const int ENA = 3; 
const int ENB = 2; 


const int echoPin = 8;  //digtal pin used for HC-SR04 ECHO in order to receive the signal
const int trigPin = 9;  //digtal pin used for HC-SR04 ECHO in order to send the signal

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(trigPin, echoPin);  //initializing the arduino pins

int distance;  
String result;  


int velocity = 0;

//on or off
boolean go = true;

float dist_cm = distance;


void setup() {

  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);   
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);      
  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);      
  pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);     

  analogWrite(ENA, 145);  
  analogWrite(ENB, 145);  
}

void loop() {  

  float distance = cmMsec();  
  dist_cm = distance;
  if (dist_cm <= 10) {

    decisao();
  }
  delay(100);
}
float cmMsec() {
  
  float cmMsec;
  long microsec = ultrasonic.timing();                    
  cmMsec = ultrasonic.convert(microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);  
  return (cmMsec);                                        
  delay(10);
}

void go_forward()  
{
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  analogWrite(ENA, velocity);
  analogWrite(ENB, velocity);
}

void freio() {  

  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  analogWrite(ENA, velocity);
  analogWrite(ENB, velocity);
}

void decisao() {

  // this block is responsible for change the speed of the car when the distance goes UP
  if (go == true) {
    if (distance > 30) {
      while (velocity < 120) {
        go_forward();
        velocity = velocity + 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (velocity >= 120) {
      while (distance >= 60 && distance <= 70) {
        siga_em_frente();
        velocity = velocity + 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (distance < 70) {
      while (velocity < 145) {
        go_forward();
        velocity = velocity + 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (velocity >= 145) {
      while (distance >= 90 && distance <= 100) {
        go_forward();
        velocity = velocity + 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (distance < 100) {
      while (velocity < 220) {
        go_forward();
        velocity = velocity + 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }
  }
  delay(10000);

  // this block is responsible for change the speed of the car when the distance goes UP
  if (go == true) {

    if (distance >= 90 && distance <= 100) {  
      while (velocity <= 145) {               
        go_forward();
        velocity = velocity - 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (velocity > 140 && velocity <= 145) {    
      while (distance >= 70 && velocity <= 60) {  
        go_forward();
        velocity = velocity - 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (distance <= 60 && velocity <= 30) {  
      while (velocity <= 120) {
        go_forward();
        velocity = velocity - 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (velocity > 110 && velocity <= 120) {
      while (distance < 30) {
        velocity = velocity - 10;
        delay(50);
      }
    }

    if (distance < 30) {
      if (velocity > 5 && velocity <= 0) {
        go = !go; 
      }
    }
  }
  if (go == true) {

    break();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int Ultrasonic::timing()
```

Is a private method. Within the Ultrasonic class that method is declared as private. That means it may only be called by the Ultrasonic class itself. It is not intended to be used by you.

In order to use it it would have to be public. So you would need to edit the class.